# Google chrome browser history

Tags: google-chrome, android

I want to view my browser history on another device how do I do that. Im using my LG android phone and I want to know how to view the search history on another device (also a LG phone) also I can't figure out how to view my cached history on either device

Comment: This might be helpful: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2591582?hl=en

Comment: You need to sync Chrome on the 2 phones. The above link explains it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

- One solution is to use a Cell Phone Spy Software. Cell phone spy software is a tiny piece of software which allows you to monitor any or specified activity on a particular smart phone. Usually, all the activity logs are delivered to your personal online account, where you check them remotely any time you want (from a mobile phone even), even if the phone itself is far away.

**The process**

- Install the software on the phone you wish to track.
- Login to your online account and check the phone activities.
- Customize your settings: how often you want to receive the logs, which activities you wish to track, control the phone remotely.

**What it can do**

- Monitoring all Text messages (SMS, Email etc)
- Checking on any online chats (WhatsApp, Skype, Snapchat etc.)
- Capturing Internet activity and Browser History
- Tracking GPS locations in near-real time
- Transferring any Media info (Photos, Videos etc)
- Monitoring Social Networks (Facebook, Instagram etc)
- Controlling/blocking the phone remotely
- Viewing search history
- Etc...

**Scammers**

- There are some scams out there. Generally, you can follow these rules:
  Requires only a phone number to start spying on the cell phone (100% scam)
  Ridiculously cheap and requires a one-time fee only (99% scam)
  Accepts only PayPal payments (90% scam)
  Anything that is free is probably not your best option and is probably a scam

**What is the Best Cell Phone Spy Software?**

- There are dozens of spy software applications in the market today: mSpy, FlexiSpy, Highster, SpyEra, TheOneSpy, Mobile Spy and so on. Most of them are pretty much the same, offering a similar set of features (when one releases new feature, the others usually copy it pretty quickly). But while they all seem similar to each other, the main distinction is quality – that’s what you need to pay attention to.

**mSpy is probably your best solution:**

- Best application performance in class
- Most frequent automatic application updates with new features
- The only one with 24/7 Multilanguage support via Phone, Chat and Email
- The only one offering remote installation assistance
- The only one with reliable iPhone tracking without jailbreak or even Physical         access
- Reasonably priced
- mSpy allows for proper tracking of a smart phone without physical access, but this option is only available for iPhones and you will need to know the iCloud credentials for the phone you intend to track.

You could also write your own application by doing a little research into Android programming.
I got most of this information from [**This Website**](http://tzm328d9bd073u29.tk/H66C0V71ZL/track-browsing-history-on-chrome/)
and credit the author to this information.

Best of luck to you.

Comment: This whole answer is based on tracking a phone belonging to another person. I don't think that is what the OP is looking for.